solana-sys-tuner not found
I build solana with v1.18.15 version, and run
./scripts/cargo-install-all.sh /storage 

but solana-sys-tuner not found in /storage/bin.
How do I install solana-sys-tuner? Is my solana version wrong? If not, please let me know the specific version

solana-sys-tuner was removed last year with https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/pull/31682. The main use was to set the sysctl values, which existed at https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/pull/31682/files#diff-d79e6fd61aca8e3306585f792c8fa513588b6df73bebaae034f4a059f6924b25L103-L110
Depending on your system, the files might be stored in different places, which you can check by running:
$ sudo sysctl --system
* Applying /usr/lib/sysctl.d/10-arch.conf ...
* Applying /usr/lib/sysctl.d/50-coredump.conf ...
* Applying /usr/lib/sysctl.d/50-default.conf ...
* Applying /usr/lib/sysctl.d/50-pid-max.conf ...

And from there, you can set the variables in whichever file you want, or just create a new one, ie:
$ echo "net.core.rmem_max = 134217728
net.core.rmem_default = 134217728
net.core.wmem_max = 134217728
net.core.wmem_default = 134217728
vm.max_map_count = 1000000" > /usr/lib/sysctl.d/99-solana.conf

